# How can I change a container color on tap with Provider?

Tags: flutter, boolean, provider

I am trying to create a custom style checkbox that is a container with rounded edges.  It should show a different color icon when tapped.  I am not sure how to do this can anyone help?  Here is the code: (Edit I updated the code to show the gridview builder that the checkbox is placed in.  The gridviewbuilder builds a card based on the length of a list in the provider class.  I am trying to get the checkbox to work independently of the other gridview cards.

```
//this is the function in the provider class
toggleCheckbox(bool checkboxStatus){
  if (checkboxStatus = false){
    return checkboxStatus = true;
  } else if (checkboxStatus = true){
    return checkboxStatus = false;
  }
  notifyListeners();
}




GridView.builder(
      
          itemCount: bloc.readingList.length,
          gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
            childAspectRatio: 12/16,  crossAxisCount: 2, crossAxisSpacing: 20.0, mainAxisSpacing: 20),
          itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
            return ClipRRect(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(16.0),
            child: Container(
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      offset: Offset(3.0, 6.0),
                      blurRadius: 10.0)
                ],
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage('${bloc.readingList[index].storyImage}'),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              child: Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                    top: 8.0, bottom: 0.0, left: 0.0, right: 0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    TopicTag(index: index,),
                    CardContents(),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          );
          },
        ),



class CardContents extends StatefulWidget {
  const CardContents({
    Key key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _CardContentsState createState() => _CardContentsState();
}

class _CardContentsState extends State<CardContents> {
  bool checkboxStatus = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final bloc = Provider.of<ReadingListBloc>(context);

    return ClipRRect(
      child: BackdropFilter(
        filter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 10.0, sigmaY: 10.0),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.blueGrey.withOpacity(.5),
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Text('Title Here (color change with topic)',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    fontSize: 18.0,
                    fontFamily: "Calibre-Semibold",
                    letterSpacing: 1.0,
                  )),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: <Widget>[
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 8.0, bottom: 8),
                    child: Container(
                      decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                          color: Colors.white),
                      child: GestureDetector(
                          onTap:(){},
                          // bloc.toggleCheckbox(checkboxStatus),
                          child: checkboxStatus
                              ? Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.green)
                              : Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Considering that you have setup your provider correctly, you could do something like below.

```
// add the property below to your provider
bool checkboxStatus = false;

void toggleCheckbox(){
  checkboxStatus = !checkboxStatus;
  notifyListeners();
}
```

Now for the listeners, you can just check this new property, considering that bloc is your provider.

```
GestureDetector(
   onTap: () {
      bloc.toggleCheckbox(checkboxStatus);
   },
   child: bloc.checkboxStatus ? Icon(Icons.check_box, color: Colors.green)
                            : Icon(Icons.check_circle, color: Colors.white)),
```

I'm assuming that for some reason you want to use a provider. Of course you could also use a StatefulWidget if you only need the status in this widget.

Comment: Hey this worked to change the checkboxes but I forgot to mention one thing sorry.  I am using a gridview builder and there needs to be a checkbox on each item.  When I check the box now, every item gets checked.  Is there a way to make it so that each individual box is checked independently?

Comment: @Dzuko that is indeed what would happen in this case. Can you add to your question the part with the GridView.builder and the provider? I would need to have a look and update my answer.

Comment: yes I just updated it, let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: @Dzuko I just added a sample project on github: https://github.com/hmasini/flutter_simple_state_management . Have a look and let me know if it can help you.